# redirecting on error 401.2 unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, web-config

I've been trying to redirect on Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration as per below:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" mode="On">
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="Unauthorized.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
```

But it never actually redirects. It still displays the default Access is denied page.
What am I doing wrong there?

Answer (score 6):

Adding the below to global.asax seems to be working just fine:

```
void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Response.StatusCode == 401)
                Response.Redirect("Unauthorized.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Try this:**

Set on your Unauthorized.aspx.cs Page_Load Method :

```
private void Page_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Put user code to initialize the page here 
    Response.StatusCode = 401;
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
}
```

See this for detail:

[HttpResponse.TrySkipIisCustomErrors Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors.aspx)

[IIS 7 Error Pages taking over 500 Errors](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Apr/29/IIS-7-Error-Pages-taking-over-500-Errors)

**Second Try this:**
Use this in addition to  tag to bypass the IIS Error page:

```
<system.webServer>
      <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: No change. Theres a way to intercept EndRequest in the global.asax but not sure how to do that. Only examples I've found are in VB

Comment: I have tried both steps above. Still not firing and just going to the YSOD. It never reaches the Unauthorized.aspx page, or even the global.asax it seems