# customErrors 401 Capturing

Tags: asp.net, web-config, http-status-code-401, custom-errors

I have been searching both Stack Overflow and various forums but I am having trouble understanding the process of capturing HTTP errors within ASP.net and IIS.

At this time I have configured by web.config with `customErrors` and a redirect for 404 and 401 errors. Placed inside the `system.web` element.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Errors/default.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly">
    <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Errors/401.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>

<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
```

However, the generic IIS error page is showing the erro: Shown below.[image]

What is missing?status codes/

Comment: The 404 is working correctly? This is happening on local or deployed?

Comment: 404 results Okay. This is happening on remote and local

Comment: Prob can find suitable answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969457/redirecting-on-error-401-2-unauthorized